# JS (Using Parse for Storage) - Value Undefined for Some Reason

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Okay, so today I was adding a new feature to my chat thing and I wanted it to whenever an admin typed `/clearchat`, it would clear the chat.

But then there is this weird bug that when I run `getAllMessages()`, it returns `undefined`. I tried printing the value it returns in the function, and that **had** a value!

Following is the code:

```
function getAllMessages() {
    var Chat = Parse.Object.extend("message");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Chat);
    query.find({
        success: function(message) {
            console.log(message);
            return message;
        },
        error: function(message, error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to actually test it out, I edited the code a little and put it on JSFiddle (Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rmvo05r4/4/)).
(Of course, I made a new Parse project so my data wouldn't get hacked)

Any help would be **highly** appreciated!

Thanks,
Oliver

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhhh

The `query.find()` function was **asynchronous**! So it was undefined at that time!